# Connect slot with constant argument

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, lambda, signals-slots

Need to connect checkbox to custom slot in tree view with constant argument, something like this:

`connect(checkBox, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), tableView, SLOT(mySlot(int col, bool)));`

1st argument type `int` should be constant like 0,1,2... How to write this correctly with new Qt 5 connection system and lambda expression in C++11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, I checked:

```
QObject::connect(checkBox, &QCheckBox::clicked, [=](bool checked) {
    tableView->mySlot(1, checked);
});
```

Comment: Whilst this is correct, the answer provided by @KerrekSB is more efficient, as it only captures the required `tableView`object in the lambda, rather than everything.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [new signal syntax documentation](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), it should be something like:

```
connect(checkBox, &CheckBox::clicked,
        [&tableView](bool b) { tableView.mySlot(2, b); });
```

Here `CheckBox` is the type of `checkBox`, and we hardcoded the value `2` as the first argument of `mySlot`.